# Javascript Classes - How to avoid calling a method over and over again?

Tags: javascript, class

I'm new to Javascript classes but I think they bring great structure to my code. However I have a feeling I could use them more efficiently.

This is an example to explain what I mean.

It takes first and last name, which it combines to a full name. A greeting phrase is constructed followed by two different questions. I notice in the console.log that the full name and the greeting phrase methods is run again every time I ask a follow-up question.

**Resulting console log:**

```
test.php:20 Benny Clark
test.php:27 Well hello there, Benny Clark!
test.php:42 Well hello there, Benny Clark! How is your day today?
test.php:20 Benny Clark
test.php:27 Well hello there, Benny Clark!
test.php:43 Well hello there, Benny Clark! Is there anything I can do for you today?
```

**Question**

Is there a smarter way to do it, to "remember" the full name and the greeting phrase so these only has to run once?

```
test.php:20 Benny Clark
test.php:27 Well hello there, Benny Clark!
test.php:42 Well hello there, Benny Clark! How is your day today?
test.php:43 Well hello there, Benny Clark! Is there anything I can do for you today?
```

**Code**

```
      class Conversation
      {
        constructor(name, surname)
        {
          this.name = name;
          this.surname = surname;
        }
        fullName()
        {
          var fullName = this.name + " " + this.surname;
          console.log(fullName);
          return fullName;
        }
        greet()
        {
          var openingPhrase = "Well hello there, ";
          var greet = openingPhrase + this.fullName() + "!";
          console.log(greet);
          return greet;
        }
        help()
        {
          var phrase = " Is there anything I can do for you today?";
          return this.greet() + phrase;
        }
        checkin()
        {
          var phrase = " How is your day today?";
          return this.greet() + phrase;
        }
      }
      var conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');
      console.log(conversation.checkin());
      console.log(conversation.help());
```

Comment: Well, the code structure is fine, the fact that it logs isn't exactly an issue, you shouldn't log in there, as it's just returning a value you are using to construct sentences somewhere else (this is where a `getter` might be more in line with the goal you are trying to accomplish). The greeting phrase should be constructed every time, although you could also accomplish that in getter and setters for name and fullname.

Comment: _"the full name and the greeting phrase methods is run again every time I ask a follow-up question"_ - Why do you `.greet()` the person before you ask/tell them something? Do you do this in real life? _"Hi Bob! How are you?"_, _"Hi Bob! Sorry to hear that."_, _"Hi Bob! Sorry for your loss."_

Comment: @Andreas TBH, sounds like some support calls I've had....

Comment: The console.log inside the Class was just to visualize whats going on when running methods on the object. Getters and setters are new to me. Do you mind sharing an implementation of them? @somethinghere

Comment: @MasterSmack - Note that getters and setters are still function calls, they just don't *look* like function calls when you get or set the property. But they are.

Comment: @Andreas "This is an example to explain what I mean", remember? The question is meant to be about calling methods not about conversation manners. 
The comment from VLAZ still gave me a laugh though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are ways, but they involve trade-offs.

Just as a preface: Don't worry too much about function calls. They're ***very*** fast in modern environments, and if they do very simple things but are also used a lot, modern JavaScript engines can optimize them aggressively (even inlining them entirely).

To your question, though: There are a couple of ways you can avoid using functions for `fullName` and `greet`:

- Build them as properties in the constructor and then again whenever `name` or `surname` changes. That means you have to make changing `name` and `surname` function calls rather than simple property assignments. If that's a lot more rare than getting the `fullName` and `greet`, it may be more efficient.
- Or you could not allow changing `name` and `surname` and then build `fullName` and `greet` in the constructor. If you're going to do that, you're probably best off making `name`, `surname`, `fullName`, and `greet` read-only properties (via `Object.defineProperty`) so that assignments to them fail. (You might have functions on the instances that let you create a new instance with a change to the `name` or `surname`.)

So as you can see, there are trade-offs. Either you incur the function call overhead when you need the `fullName` and `greet`, or you incur the function call overhead when you need to set `name` or `surname`, or you make instances of your class immutable (at least in this regard).

You can define an API for your class that makes all of these things (`name`, `surname`, `fullName`, and `greet`) look like properties by defining at least some of them as *accessor* properties. Accessor properties are ones where getting the property or setting it is a function call, but doesn't *look* like a function call. It is still one, though.

For instance, here's an example where `name` and `surname` are accessor properties and `fullName` and `greet` are read-only properties (I'm not advocating doing this, just giving you an example):

```js
class Conversation {
    constructor(name, surname) {
        this._name = name;
        this._surname = surname;
        this.update();
    }
    set name(value) {
        this._name = value;
        this.update();
    }
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }
    set surname(value) {
        this._surname = value;
        this.update();
    }
    get surname() {
        return this._surname;
    }
    update() {
        const openingPhrase = "Well hello there, ";
        Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
            value: this.name + " " + this.surname,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, "greet", {
            value: openingPhrase + this.fullName + "!",
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    }
    help() {
        const phrase = " Is there anything I can do for you today?";
        return this.greet + phrase;
    }
    checkin() {
        const phrase = " How is your day today?";
        return this.greet + phrase;
    }
}
const conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');
console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
conversation.name = "Paul";
console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
```

That example uses other properties which are also public, just prefixed with a `_` which is a convention saying "leave these alone." But JavaScript **very** nearly has [truly private fields][1] now (they're in modern JavaScript engines already), so here's that same example using them:

```js
class Conversation {
    #name;
    #surname;
    constructor(name, surname) {
        this.#name = name;
        this.#surname = surname;
        this.update();
    }
    set name(value) {
        this.#name = value;
        this.update();
    }
    get name() {
        return this.#name;
    }
    set surname(value) {
        this.#surname = value;
        this.update();
    }
    get surname() {
        return this.#surname;
    }
    update() {
        const openingPhrase = "Well hello there, ";
        Object.defineProperty(this, "fullName", {
            value: this.name + " " + this.surname,
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, "greet", {
            value: openingPhrase + this.fullName + "!",
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    }
    help() {
        const phrase = " Is there anything I can do for you today?";
        return this.greet + phrase;
    }
    checkin() {
        const phrase = " How is your day today?";
        return this.greet + phrase;
    }
}
const conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');
console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
conversation.name = "Paul";
console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, and it's not an issue that something gets ran more often, you want the data to be up to date. There are ways to automate this process, but since you are trying to have a conversation, that might get cumbersome in code to update any text in the future. I would suggest to use a getter and/or setter for your commonly used items (because they're a class feature and make your code more legible - they're just methods as well, as @T.J.Crowder pointed out in the comments), as well as template strings to make combining them easier:

```js
class Conversation {
   
    get fullName(){ return `${this.name} ${this.surname}` }
    get greeting(){ return `Well hello there, ${this.fullName}!`; }
    
    constructor( name, surname ){
    
      this.name = name;
      this.surname = surname;
      
    }
  
    /* These could be getter/setter as well, to be honest, but it feels like these are entry methods and not commonly used data, so I presume you are going to want to do soe more here */
    help(){

      return `${this.greeting} Is there anything I can do for you today?`;

    }
    checkin(){

      return `${this.greeting}. How is your day today?`;

    }
    
}
      
const conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');

console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
```

Using getters/setter or very simple methods is the whole point of making more legible code that works as expected, don't worry too much about storing every string. Think about it like this: if we are only going to display it once, or only every so often, is it better to use up some memory permanently or use some small value of processing power to construct it on run time? I would say the latter is the best option.

After reading @Andreas comment and thinking about it, your structure could be better like this, imagining the console is your conversation output:

```js
class Conversation {
   
    get fullName(){ return `${this.name} ${this.surname}` }
    
    constructor( name, surname ){
    
      this.name = name;
      this.surname = surname;
      
    }
    
    greet(){
    
      return `Well hello there, ${this.fullName}!`;
    
    }
  
    help(){

      return `Is there anything I can do for you today?`;

    }
    checkin(){

      return `How is your day today?`;

    }
    
}
      
const conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');

console.log(conversation.greet());
console.log(conversation.checkin());
console.log(conversation.help());
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the input! I will look more into getters and setters to see if they are the right way to go

Comment: Don't forget that they are just methods as well, if you worry about calling them too often that doesn't exactly solve your problem, but I hope it's also clear that calling methods is really fast, and combining strings is a negligibly small and fast operation. Definitely also check out @T.J.Crowder's answer, it contains a different approach that might be interesting, but it introduces a bit of complexity, so be sure that the trade off is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make it log your desired output, you can use memoization to log only if the value is initialized:

```js
class Conversation
      {
        constructor(name, surname)
        {
          this.name = name;
          this.surname = surname;
        }
        fullName()
        {
          if (this._fullName) return this._fullName;
          var fullName = this._fullName = this.name + " " + this.surname;
          console.log(fullName);
          return fullName;
        }
        greet()
        {
          if (this._greet) return this._greet;
          var openingPhrase = "Well hello there, ";
          var greet = this._greet = openingPhrase + this.fullName() + "!";
          console.log(greet);
          return greet;
        }
        help()
        {
          var phrase = " Is there anything I can do for you today?";
          return this.greet() + phrase;
        }
        checkin()
        {
          var phrase = " How is your day today?";
          return this.greet() + phrase;
        }
      }
      var conversation = new Conversation('Benny', 'Clark');
      console.log(conversation.checkin());
      console.log(conversation.help());
```

Comment: What happens when the name or surname get updated but there's already a private `_greet` set? I think the trade of of saving this data in memory is not worth the code...

Comment: @somethinghere 1. This is just a silly example, not a production code. This is just a way to make code work as OP wants. 2. Instance properties shouldn't really be changed directly. There should be a method for it like `changeName()` that would also clear private props.

Comment: I don't agree that instance properties shouldn't be changed, if so then define the as read-only, but that's not the case here. You have basically solved an issue by introducing another one, and made the OPs code less versatile in the process.

Comment: @somethinghere okaay, seems like you're very serous about your opinions. AFAIK directly setting properties is against encapsulation which is quite important in OOP. Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state.